# A definite integral with a real parameter

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $\alpha\in[0,1]$, and
$$\text{I}(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(t)}{(1-t)\sqrt{1-\alpha t}}\text{d}t$$

I need to find a general close form for the function $\text{I}(\alpha)$, but I'm really strugling on this one.

I can get the specific values for $\alpha=0$ and $1$ ($-\zeta(2)$ and $-4\ln(2)$ respectively), but not the general expression. None of the usual integration technique seem to apply here. Seeing those 2 values, I expect an expression involving logarithms and dilogarithms...

Do you have any insight ?

Comment: @Zacky I don't think the integral$$\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\, x^n(1-x)^{-1}$$converges for the beta function.

Comment: Using a CAS, the antiderivative is obtained : a "nice" monster which involves in particular several polylogarithms. $I(\alpha)$ is just a monster !

Comment: Ah, I feared that... Thank you anyway

Comment: Essentially you are asking for a closed form for $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right]H_n^{(2)}\alpha^n$$ or $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right]\frac{H_n}{n}\beta^n.$$ They can be shown to be expressible in terms of polylogarithms by Fourier-Legendre expansions, see Campbell, Sondow, me, Cantarini, Di Trani.

Comment: Wow, the first one is actually exactly what I was looking for. I already have the closed form for the second power series (involving dilogarithm indeed), but you are saying that I can derive the first one from it ?

Comment: @HarmonicSun: of course, such series are deeply related via the change of variable $t\mapsto 1-t$ and the comparison of $\int_{0}^{1}x^n\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx$ with $\int_{0}^{1}x^n\frac{\log x}{1-x}\,dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With substitution $t=1-u$
$$\text{I}(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u\sqrt{(1-\alpha)+\alpha u}}\ \mathrm{d}t =- \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^n}{nu\sqrt{(1-\alpha)+\alpha u}}\ \mathrm{d}u$$
now let $\dfrac{\alpha u}{1-\alpha}=\dfrac{w}{1-w}$ therefore
$$\text{I}(\alpha)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{-1}{n} \dfrac{(1-\alpha)^{n-1/2}}{\alpha^n} \int_{0}^{\alpha}w^{n-1}(1-w)^{-n-\frac12}\ \mathrm{d}w = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{-1}{n} \dfrac{(1-\alpha)^{n-1/2}}{\alpha^n} \beta\left(\alpha;n,-n+\frac12\right)$$
where $\beta(x;a,b)$ is [incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

Comment: I guess this is the best we can get, right ? Thank you

Comment: You are welcome dear.

Answer (score 2):

With the change of variable $t\mapsto 1-t$ the problem boils down to finding a closed form for
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta t}}\,dt=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}\beta^n}{4^n}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n-1}\log(1-t)\,dt=-\zeta(2)-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}\beta^n H_n}{n 4^n} $$
which should be

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}\beta^n H_n}{n 4^n} = -4\log^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{\beta}-1}\right)+\log^2\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\beta}}\right)-2\log\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\beta}}\right)\log\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\beta}}\right)-2\,\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\beta}}\right)$$
if I managed to simplify correctly the CAS-assisted manipulations through Fourier-Legendre series.